# TextView String(s) not appearing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

(Novice Android Dev.)

So I'm trying to display some text in a fragment. I've hardcoded the strings however the values are not showing up. For some reason it is just showing "TextView" Am I missing something? Do I have to declare this in the respective fragment.java fragment? If so, can I get some help on how to do so.

Much obliged.
[[image: fragment_schedule.xml[1]]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="org.coc.stthomas.stthomascoc.ScheduleFragment">

<CalendarView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    tools:text="Divine Liturgy: 8am"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    tools:text="Sunday School: 5pm"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    tools:text="J.H. + H.S. Meeting: 7:15pm"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView7" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    tools:text="Bible Study: 7:15pm"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView8" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    tools:text="Midnight Praises: 8pm"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView9" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/friday"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    tools:text="Friday"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/saturday"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    tools:text="Saturday"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    tools:text="Divine Liturgy: 8am"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView11" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/sunday"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    tools:text="Sunday"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    tools:text="Hymns Class: 11:45am"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView14" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    tools:text="Vespers: 6:30pm"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView6" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    tools:text="Pre-Servants Class: 1pm"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView15" />
```

Comment: Instead of tools:text use android:text to display the strings in screen.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show text on a TextView you should use `android:text="Divine Liturgy: 8am"` instead of  `tools:text="Divine Liturgy: 8am"`

Or make changes in your Java file, define TextView in Java like

```
TextView text1 = (TextView) context.findViewByID(R.id.textView14);
text1.setText("Divine Liturgy: 8am");
```

Comment: Could you explain what the difference is? It seems easier to edit the former

Comment: This is for if you want to change your TextView text grammatically.

Comment: So in order to change TextView grammatically, I must define it in my Java File? Would it be the specific java file for that activity/fragment or the main activity?

Comment: Sorry that is programmatically.

Comment: This is depends on you, where you inflating your view. Either on activity/fragment or your MainActivity class.

Answer (score 1):

Try just using

```
android:text="To Display"
```

As far as I know, the `tools` definitions are only for the preview in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

`android:text` --> what you would see while running the app

`tools:text` --> what you would see just on preview window (when you need to design layout, but won't it to see on layout in app)

[reference](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/different-between-androidtext-and-toolstext)